# Alternate ways to upload files with no input tag. Java selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

DOM doesn't include input tag for upload button. Upload button does not work manually unless I have Web Capture Service software downloaded. If I disable the web capture service and try to click the upload button, nothing happens no dialog box pop up nothing. I have tried to see if an input tag is created after the fact of uploading a file, but nope.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Whenever we don't have input tag , we use Robot Class. I am adding code below & you just need to call uploadFile Method in your code.

i.e  uploadFile("C://test.pdf") ;

```
public static void setClipboardData(String string) 
{
/StringSelection is a class that can be used for copy and paste operations.
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
}

public static void uploadFile(String fileLocation) 
 {
  try{
  //Setting clipboard with file location
  setClipboardData(fileLocation);
  //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 } catch (Exception exp) 
  {
   exp.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

**Hope it helps you.Keep Learning.Keep Growing.Best wishes.**

Comment: Thanks for the response, in parallel execution I imagine robot class won't' work well. I also need it to run in headless on the pipeline.